# R Date Internal Integer Storage Has "L" - Can it be removed?

Tags: r, date, structure

I have an API that returns

```
 str(test)
'data.frame':   35 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date   : Date, format: "2017-05-23" "2017-05-24" "2017-05-25" "2017-05-26" ...
 $ PX_LAST: num  52.3 52.1 49.8 50.6 50.5 ...
```

However, on closer look at the internal storage of the date variable... the dates are stored with an "L" appended to the end.

```
dput(test)
structure(list(date = structure(c(17309L, 17310L, 17311L, 17312L, 
17316L, 17317L, 17318L, 17319L, 17322L, 17323L, 17324L, 17325L, 
17326L, 17329L, 17330L, 17331L, 17332L, 17333L, 17336L, 17337L, 
17338L, 17339L, 17340L, 17343L, 17344L, 17345L, 17346L, 17347L, 
17350L, 17352L, 17353L, 17354L, 17357L, 17358L, 17359L), class = "Date"), 
    PX_LAST = c(52.3, 52.09, 49.76, 50.59, 50.48, 49.12, 49.22, 
    48.51, 48.22, 48.88, 46.87, 46.85, 46.97, 47.15, 47.45, 45.82, 
    45.67, 45.94, 45.46, 44.58, 43.51, 43.74, 44.08, 44.4, 45.31, 
    45.81, 46.02, 47.05, 48.01, 46.1, 46.4, 45.07, 45.32, 45.92, 
    46.64)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", "PX_LAST"
), row.names = c(NA, 35L))
```

Is there anyway to change the way the date is stored to get r=rid of the L at the end? That extra L is causing an error when I try to write the data to sql database.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the comments, rich, d.b. and Marius. Here is the SQL code that i'm using to write to the database.

OK in the spirit of trying to replicate this very confusing problem. I've done this. Here's the structure of one line of the data table that yields the restricted data type problem:

```
> oneLine <- flatFrame[1, 1-4]
> str(oneLine)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Ticker  : Factor w/ 1 level "CLU7 Comdty": 1
 $ date    : Date, format: "2017-05-18"
 $ VOLUME  : num 44674
 $ OPEN_INT: int 188049
```

Then I try to write this one line to the database in a new table and I get the attribute violation error.

```
dbWriteTable(con, "new7", oneLine, verbose=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1791: 07006: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
Server]Restricted data type attribute violation
```

So now I try to clone the data frame:

```
rep_data <- data.frame(Ticker=as.factor("CLU7 Comdty"), date = as.Date("2017-05-18"), VOLUME=44674, OPEN_INT =as.integer(188049))
> str(rep_data)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Ticker  : Factor w/ 1 level "CLU7 Comdty": 1
 $ date    : Date, format: "2017-05-18"
 $ VOLUME  : num 44674
 $ OPEN_INT: int 188049
```

Exactly the same....But this write function produces no error.

```
dbWriteTable(con, "new8", rep_data, verbose=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

What is going on? Is there some phantom attribute in the data table that I'm not seeing?

Someone on github suggested that I use the `dput()` command to look at the internal structure of the data.

```
dput(oneLine)
structure(list(Ticker = structure(1L, .Label = "CLU7 Comdty", class = "factor"), 
date = structure(17304L, class = "Date"), VOLUME = 44674, 
OPEN_INT = 188049L), .Names = c("Ticker", "date", "VOLUME", 
"OPEN_INT"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

dput(rep_data)
structure(list(Ticker = structure(1L, .Label = "CLU7 Comdty", class = "factor"), 
date = structure(17304, class = "Date"), VOLUME = 44674, 
OPEN_INT = 188049L), .Names = c("Ticker", "date", "VOLUME", 
"OPEN_INT"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

The salient difference in the date structure is that in the one that fails, oneLine, the internally stored date 17304**L** has an "L" appended to it. The replicated data set does not.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Dates are integers under the hood, and that is how integers are stored in R.  You might be able to do `test$date <- as.double(test$date)` then re-transform it back later.

Comment: what exactly are you writing to the sql database. Is it the date strings or those integers without the `L`?

Comment: I think the problem might be the way you're writing to the database. AFAIK the `L` usually only shows up when you're seeing R's internal representation of something, and doesn't affect how those values are written when outputting or saving the data. Can you show example code of how you write the data?

Comment: For posterity's sake, please put pertinent information in the post so it's not reliant on an external site.

Comment: Aaron - All of the SQL related lines are on the stackoverflow post. Do you think I need to repost those here again? I merely included the link to gitHub because no one responded to my stackoverflow post, and someone may want to look at those comments.

Comment: IMO the material in this question properly belongs as a further set of edits to your previous question.

Comment: if no-one responded to your previous post, posting a new question is not the right solution ...

Comment: PS there is interesting (IMO) stuff going on with numeric vs integer representations from `as.Date` ... commented on some in the associated post.

Comment: PPS `d$date <- as.Date(d$date,origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: About the links, I didn't bother following them. Which is another reason to post self-contained questions, I doubt I'm the only one. :) I've now looked and agree with Ben that it's really just one question. Please combine, probably here, now that this one has an answer.

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, interestingly, that doesn't change the internal representation; see my last edit.

Comment: huh, I thought it did.  Must have messed up.

Comment: Ok the solution works. I will delete the other post. I felt that this was more of a data structure question than a SQL one, which was why I created a new thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems that the function needs the internal representation of a `Date` to be a numeric instead of an integer; if so, we just need to convert the existing integers to numeric and then to Dates.

Note that the problem is not that there's an "L"; that's just how an integer is output for display to tell you that it's an integer, it's not internally used at all. So unless your other function is parsing the output from `dput` (very unlikely), the problem is one of converting to integer, not removing an L.

I'll first check the usual representation; it does use numerics, not integers (note no L).

```
> dput(as.Date("2017-07-01"))
structure(17348, class = "Date")
```

Now I'll make a version that has an integer underneath, it does seem to work okay for this purpose, but apparently not for yours.

```
> (foo <- structure(17348L, class="Date"))
[1] "2017-07-01"
> dput(foo)
structure(17348L, class = "Date")
```

So here's how you would convert it to a numeric and then back to a Date. R's origin date is 1970-01-01 but instead of hardcoding that I cast 0 to be a Date.

```
> (foo2 <- as.Date(as.numeric(foo), origin=structure(0, class="Date")))
[1] "2017-07-01"
> dput(foo2)
structure(17348, class = "Date")
```

I bet if you do this to your date column it'll work.

Interestingly, just recasting as new Date doesn't change to numeric.

```
> dput(as.Date(foo, origin="1970-01-01"))
structure(17348L, class = "Date")
```